# Inner join в tableAdapter вопрос по реализации

Tags: winforms, ado.net, mysql

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане. В меру своей неопытности позволю уточнить у Вас одну деталь:
Предположим у меня ест справочная таблица медикаментов и таблица заказов медикаментов. 
Упрощённый вариант:

```
Справочная таблица :

medID | medTitle | price
---------------------------

Таблица заказов :

orderID | medID | count
----------------------------
```

И в таблице заказов я хочу вместо medID показать информацию рассчитанную на пользователя, выбрав её из справочной таблицы, но при этом чтобы записывался MedID.
Проблем (в теории) вроде бы нет, я изменяю запрос объекта Table Adapter, добавляя INNER JOIN, скрываю medID в dataGridView, но тогда слетит всё приложение... Потому как делаю всё это я на этапе проектирования, и после объединения он просто очистит свойства UpdateCommand и InsertCommand объекта DataAdapter... Подскажите, где на этапе проектирования искать эти свойства чтобы не возникало вот таких вот проблем...
Заранее благодарен за понимание и помощь...

Comment: @Богдан Добровольский, в след раз,  чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

и сделайте sqlfiddle

Comment: LEFT JOIN не?

Comment: Вопрос заключался в том что я не могу найти где руками прописать свойства UpdateCommand и InsertCommand